# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'discussion_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `replies`

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'discussion_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `replies` (`content`, `discussion_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asdfghjl, ?, 1, 2021-05-09 03:09:05, 2021-05-09 03:09:05)).

**Here is my reply model**

```
<?php

namespace LaravelForum;



class Reply extends Model
 {
   public function users()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }

   public function discussion()
    {
   
    return $this->belongsTo(Discussion::class);
    }

 }
```

**reply table**

```
   <?php

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

   class CreateRepliesTable extends Migration
    {
     /**
      * Run the migrations.
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function up()
      {
        Schema::create('replies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('discussion_id');
            $table->string('content');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
      }

        /**
       * Reverse the migrations.
       *
       * @return void
       */
     public function down()
     {
       Schema::dropIfExists('replies');
     }
 }
```

**Discussion model**

```
  <?php

  namespace LaravelForum;



  class Discussion extends Model
  {
    public function author()
     {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
     }

   public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
    return 'slug';
    }




  }
```

**discussion table**

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDiscussionsTable extends Migration
 {
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function up()
    {
         Schema::create('discussions', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->integer('user_id');
           $table->string('title');
           $table->text('content');
           $table->string('slug');
           $table->integer('channel_id');
           $table->timestamps();
       });
    }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
    {
      Schema::dropIfExists('discussions');
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed Discussion Id While insert into  database .... It will be great
if you send image of insert query from controller or check it out there.

Comment: Here is the store method of controller:                                                                   public function store(CreateReplyRequest $request, Discussion $discussion)
    {
     
        auth()->user()->replies()->create([
            'content'=>$request->content,
            'discussion_id'=>$request->id
           

        ]);

Comment: log $request->id in controller using echo verify weather it is available or not

Comment: I am new in laravel i can not get how to check specific query. Give me some instruction.

Comment: in you store controller public function store(CreateReplyRequest $request, Discussion $discussion) { return dd($request->id)}

Comment: I have checked it and it shows null. But i have a discussion in database.

Comment: so you need to put document_id while updating  and cause of error is not having id... hope you understand clearly.

Comment: i have putted document_id replacing id but not working.

Comment: send complete code by putting it in github and send to me i will fix it by and add comment in refrence..... thanks

Comment: I think you should use `$discussion->id` instead of `$request->id`  in `'discussion_id'=>$request->id `

Comment: Mahdi Jedari thank you so much .its working.

Comment: Ok happy to know